# Can I pursue a degree and career in I.T security as a felon?

Tags: career-switch, background-check, tech-industry

I am 23 years old and a recent convicted felon and my charge is misuse of a two-way device. I was a paramedic before I got into some trouble, and I cant go back into the medical field. I.T security caught my eye and I was wondering if I can pursue that career in my situation, or what careers I can pursue. I want to know that I'll be able to get a job  before I start pursuing a degree because I don't want to waste my time and money in a field I won't be able to get a job in.

Comment: Most IT Security jobs (all the ones I'm aware of, but there may be others) require security clearance; your conviction *may* cause a red flag.

Comment: The crime "misuse of a two-way device" is fairly vague and appears to basically mean you used your cell phone to help commit a felony. The nature of the primary crime may make a big difference here. Helping someone embezzle funds or commit fraud would be much worse for IT Security than vandalism or alcohol related crimes.

Comment: What jurisdiction is this is? United States? Laws vary wildly.

Comment: @PeteCon Only government jobs would require clearance, or government contractors.  Nobody in the private world has one.  Now that's not to say the felony won't hurt in other ways.  What it sounds like its for doesn't help-  you could talk your way out of a posession or assault conviction being a problem by being contrite, but something that sounds like fraud is scary.

Comment: @Gabe: I work in IT Security, and I was required to pass clearance before working on any client production servers. We don't do any government work. I think you'll find that a lot of pro security firms in the US require clearance (but of course, that's opinion only..)

Comment: @PeteCon I've worked in programming for 17 years.  The only people I know who have security clearance, including those in IT security, work for the feds or contractors.  I've never heard of someone else even getting one-  I was fairly certain you had to have a government contractor sponsor you to even start the process.  Are you sure you have actual clearance, and not some other type of background check (which would be very common)?

Comment: @PeteCon According to https://www.state.gov/m/ds/clearances/c10977.htm#1  and several other sources you must have a job that works for the federal government and requires clearance to even begin the process.  So either you do work for a government contractor, or you don't have security clearance.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly not.

You can't pass a background check and that would disqualify you immediately for any job with the word "security" in it.  You're basically uninsurable for liability purposes.

Comment: It's my experience and I stand by it.  You obviously don't agree so I encourage you to make your **own answer** telling him that everything will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try and cultivate contacts in the security field who could better advise you.  See if there is a job fair in your area that is highlighting security jobs, or the professors in a security program and ask them.  Both groups will tell you if they think you would be wasting your (and their) time.

I assume you have already looked into this, but if this was your first offence I have heard of programs that can get your record expunged after a certain amount of time.  For that of course I would consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get your record expunged, I would suggest that.  Otherwise, network with people.

A good connection can open doors normally closed.  I've gotten several jobs that have required degrees, of which I have none, but I'm damn good at what I do.

If the felony has nothing to do with a breach of security or theft, you **MAY** be able to overcome it, but at best it is a longshot.  Sometimes people who go into "ethical hacking" can sneak in with a conviction if they have high enough skills.

IF this is a passion for you, you may want to try freelancing for smaller companies.  They are less likely to do a background check and care more about results than a big company with set procedures.

According to stack exchange law, you may be able to answer "no" as to a conviction if it has been expunged, but I'd consult a lawyer to make sure.

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3572/if-someones-record-has-been-expunged-can-they-legally-say-that-they-have-not-b

Comment: You don't get popped for felony misuse of a two-way device as a lookout to j-walk.

Comment: @Paparazzi Yep, I looked it up.  It's a third degree felony if, and only if, the misuse is in the facilitation of another felony.  Sounds like theft of medical supplies.

Comment: I should add that, even if you get your record is expunged, doesn't mean you can lie when you are ask if you have been convicted of a felony.  If you lie and get a job that requires a background check, and it's discovered, that's grounds for termination immediately.  Depending on the situation even worse

Comment: @Ramhound stack exchange law disagrees https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3572/if-someones-record-has-been-expunged-can-they-legally-say-that-they-have-not-b

Answer (score -6):

IT security is very sensitive to convictions. You have access to data. Even a misdemeanor can nix you. A DWI can fail a background check. A raw programmer there will be limited opportunities. Stay away from the data.

Comment: It would depend on the misdemeanor. I have one (FTA) and it's never been a hindrance at all.

Comment: As you pointed out Christopher, provided you are upfront about the misdemeanor, it won't be a problem.  People get in more trouble for hiding something like that then they would if they were just honest about it

Comment: @Ramhound You can speak for every IT security job and a misdemeanor is not a problem as long as you are upfront?

Comment: What do people find wrong with this answer?